# Cache on demand from GeoWebCache

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

Is there a way to set GeoServer/GeoWebcache to cache on demand i.e. instead of having it tie the server up for days, whilst it caches millions upon millions of tiles, can it be set to cache tiles (to GWC cache directory on the server) as they are served?

That would mean, of course, that the first person to request tiles may have a  slower experience to start with but they and everyone else would be served cached tiles thereafter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the default behavior, see also https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/index.html
It says: caching (storing) tiles as they are requested, eliminating redundant request processing and thus saving large amounts of processing time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, though I am not convinced it is doing that. My reason is that I am watching the GWC directory and as tiles are requested, they are not being put into that directory. They are being cached in the browser but not on the server.

I am running GWC 'out of the box' pretty much, so  it also does not appear to be default behaviour.

I will check further for settings but was hoping that someone with more experience in this than I have (I'm pretty much a newbie to this) would be able to give me some pointers as to where to look.

Comment: Make a default GeoServer installation with the demo data. Have a look at directory \data_dir\gwc\topp_states. Notice that it is empty. Then go to demo http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/demo/topp:states?gridSet=EPSG:900913&format=image/png and see what happens. If you are using the layer preview, it is requesting tiles from WMS, not from GWC.

Comment: If you activate the "Enable direct integration with GeoServer WMS" setting from the Caching defaults and then change the layer preview to make tiled requests (the default is single tile) then you should see tiles to appear also when zooming and panning on the States preview.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for your response.  If I enable the direct integration, will it cache absolutely everything, or just the zoom levels set in the gridsets?
The reason I ask that is that we have a huge set of OS raster tiles and if they all get cached, we will likely burst our available storage (currently 2TB).
If it will cache only the zoom levels set in the gridsets, then that would be a perfect solution.
Thanks

Comment: You asked about on demand caching and if you enable direct integration without seeding then tiles are cached just as you described. Zoom levels and tiles that your users can't access will not be cached. You will probably notice also that large areas are never visited and cached.

Comment: Hi @user30184. Thank you for the advice. I will apply it to a test server ready for my next update.  Also, after going through the settings again and also receiving some additional advice, I realised that my understanding of gridsdets was somewhat lacking. I have been able to recreate the cache by ensuring I have the correct bounds and resolutions in my gridset. Although caching has not yet completed, It is looking much better in terms of number of tiles and time to completion.
I will mark this answer as accepted.
Thank you and also _webrian for the initial reply.